# is it possible to keep redux dispatch function in class performing async actions?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am beginner in Redux and I want to use it for asynchronous logic. Redux style quide [recommends](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-thunks-for-async-logic) to use `redux-thunk` for it, but it seems I don't need it if I use redux in following way:

```js
class Actions {
  constructor(dispatch) {
    this.dispatch = dispatch;
  }

  someSyncAction1(data) {
    this.dispatch({
      type: SOME_SYNC_ACTION1,
      payload: data,
    })
  }

  someSyncAction2(data) {
    this.dispatch({
      type: SOME_SYNC_ACTION2,
      payload: data,
    })
  }
  
  async someAsyncAction(data1, data2) {
    this.someSyncAction1(data1);
    await somethingAsync();
    this.someSyncAction2(data2);
  }
}

// then in my react component:
function MyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const actions = new Actions(dispatch);
  
  //...
  return <div onClick={() => actions.someAsyncAction(1, 2)}></div>;
}
```

It seems to be a simple way but I worry whether it can lead to errors. Please help me to understand what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very different from the `useActions` hook referred to in the [Hooks documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#recipe-useactions) - at least for the synchronous stuff.

In the async stuff, you are losing functionality though: Thunks can at any given time access the current state by calling `getState`.

Also, and this is probably more important: thunks are not only recommended, they are a pattern almost every redux developer knows. So they look at your code and can immediately go to work. Your pattern on the other hand is not established, so it will lead to conflicts if someone other will ever take over your code - without any real benefit.